# Expected value of Z operator in GHZ state

Tags: amazon-braket

I'm following [this](https://github.com/aws/amazon-braket-examples/blob/main/examples/getting_started/1_Running_quantum_circuits_on_simulators.ipynb) notebook written using amazon-braket, and there's a statement I don't understand

> ... To reiterate, the following output is expected:
> $$\left|\mathrm{GHZ}\right> = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\left|0,0,0\right> + \left|1,1,1\right>\right) = \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,0,0,0,0,0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right],
> $$
> for which $\color{red}{\left<ZZZ\right>=0}$ and $\left<111|\mathrm{GHZ}\right>=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

The highlighted expression is the one I'm having troubles with. Isn't that expectation value $1/2$ instead?

\begin{eqnarray}
\left<\mathrm{GHZ}|ZZZ|\mathrm{GHZ}\right> &=& \frac{1}{2}\left(
\left<000|ZZZ|000\right> +
\left<000|ZZZ|111\right> +
\left<111|ZZZ|000\right> +
\left<111|ZZZ|111\right>
\right) \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}\left(0 + 0 + 0 + 1 \right) \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}
\end{eqnarray}

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your off-diagonal contributions are correct, since $Z$ is diagonal in this basis, but your diagonal contributions seem to be taking the values of the kets to be the values of the $Z$ operator's diagonal.  The $Z$ operator written in the basis of $\{ |0\rangle, |1\rangle \}$ is
$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$.  So $\langle iii|ZZZ|iii \rangle$ is $(+1)^3$ for $i=0$ and $(-1)^3$ for $i=1$, yielding the stated result of 0.

Comment: I'm such an idiot, I was assuming $\{|0\rangle, |1\rangle \}$ were the eigenstates of $Z$, $Z|z\rangle = z|z\rangle$, thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh, but $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ are the eigenstates of $Z$! However, the corresponding eigenvalues are not equal to the labels of the states. Instead, we have $Z|z\rangle=(-1)^z|z\rangle$.